# AutoHotKey:how to get the errorlevel of find command?

Tags: windows, cmd, autohotkey

I have a job that I want to assign it to AHK to run for me in 5 minute intervals.
It needs to check the contents of a txt file, lets say c:\test.txt.
This file can contain any number of lines in the format of:

```
prog 1
prog 2
prog 3
  ...
prog N
```

among lines containing other pieces of text.

My purpose is to tell AHK the number right after the word prog, on the last line, which is the largest number in the list as these lines come in numeric sequence in this file.

My grandiose idea is to check the existence of lines from "prog 1" to "prog N", where N is a number under 20, using a series of find commands on a cmd window, get the errorlevel back and when errorlevel hits 1, I will set my desired variable to the value of the value of the loop index minus 1, as it was the last successfully ran find command, as such

```
i=1
loop 20
{
  type c:\users\me\test.txt | find "prog "%i%
  if  %errorlevel% != 0 
  { 
     num := i-1
     ; exit the loop in some way here
  }
  else 
  {
     i := i+1
  }
 } ; end loop
```

At this point, all I am interested in is the value stored in variable %num%. I know it may not be the most elegant solution to accomplish this but for a few runs everyday on an otherwise idle laptop, I can take the performance penalties.

So far, I am stuck at the very basic component of this idea: find command and passing the errorlevel it generates back to AHK

here is my code: (this code is only for the testing of find command, which I got from AHK forums)

```
Run %COMSPEC% /K type c:\users\me\test.txt | find "prog 4", , max
msgbox %ErrorLevel%
return
```

when this piece of code runs, the messagebox always displays the value "0" regardless "prog 4" line is there or not.

when I replace command Run with RunWait, then errorlevel gets displayed as one expects, but in that case, my automation process runs into a glitch: Expecting manual effort to close the cmd prompt, which I am assuming the *feature" of the Wait portion of the command RunWait.

How can I get over this hurdle ? I am open to loading the whole functionality to a dos batch file and getting a numeric output from the batch file at the end, but I came to realize, programming with AHK is much easier to do and to understand than that of DOS batch programming. So, my preference is on the AHK scripting side.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use RegEx to extract the last item:

```
FileRead, cont, test.txt
RegExMatch(cont, "s).*prog (\d+)", num)
msgbox, Hightest number: %num1%
```

AutoHotkey should be sufficient most of the time when it comes to arithmetics/string operations. Calling other applications for simple things like this is kind of an overkill and will most likely slow you down.

Explanation for the RegEx:

- `s)` determines that the period (**.**) will match each character including any newline (`\r` and/or `\n`). By default, it would stop at the first line break. See [RegEx options](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm#Options).
- `.*` is a standard pattern that will match anything. It is the key to find the last item in our string, because it will consume as much as possible as long as the pattern is still satisfied. In other words, it will discard everything up until the last `prog n`, which is exactly what we want. See [Greed in the RegEx reference](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm#Greed).
- `(\d+)` does 2 things: 1) It will find any integer number sequence 2) It will create a subpattern and store the number where we can explicitely access it later.

The output var (here: `num`) will be a pseudo array containing any matched subpattern plus the entire pattern that was matched. Printing `%num%` will show you almost the whole file, up to the last `prog n`. `%num1%` will contain the first subpattern, which is the biggest `n`.

Comment: Thank you.. if this works, it would be a god-sent. Since I don't have AHK on my office laptop, I will test it first thing this evening

Comment: @Mel_Burslan Great, although I don't know what time zone you're in ;)

Comment: sorry for the late response. Life gets in the way sometimes. your 3 lines of code worked perfectly and was what I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: @Mel_Burslan You're welcome. It would be an even bigger pleasure if you told me that you've also understood what the code does!

Comment: I'll admit RegexMatch command is not something I could figure out on my own but here it goes what I understood from your command: (cont, "s) construct is lost on me other than cont referring to the material read from open file; then *prog matches the prog phrase in my search string; (\d+) matches to one or more numeric digits; and the final value found is assigned to variable %num%. And how %num% becomes %num1% in the msgbox command is lost on me as well, but I am sensing and array of values and this being the first one of the values, where the s) can be thought as "sort". How did I do ?

Comment: @Mel_Burslan Have a look at the edit. Feel free to ask any follow-up questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to do all of this within AutoHotkey, this is how I would do it

```
FileRead, Content, C:\test.txt
Loop, parse, Content, `n
{
    RegExMatch(A_Loopfield, "(?i)(?<=prog\s)[\d]+", match)
    If (match > lastMatch)
        lastMatch := match
}

msgbox % lastMatch
```

**Edited to always get highest value**

Comment: not really.. this is good for getting one particular prog number. What I am after is the last and the greatest number of prog X string out there. The "prog X" lines come in numeric order and can go up to 20, but in any 5 minute interval, the number of prog lines in the file can be anywhere from 3 to 20. I want to find out what is the highest number prog X line, in my file. And as my original question indicated, I have lines with other content in the same file. I can use your construct in a loop from 1 to 20 for the prog index, but it sounds it would be too complex to a level of overkill.

Comment: @Mel_Burslan There's no way around reading the file entirely. The most performant way I imagine would be to read the whole file at once (no looping). You can then either count the occurences of `prog` or extract the number attached to the last occurence.

Comment: @Mel_Burslan Just so I'm understanding correctly, you want to get the highest Prog X in the file every 5 minutes?

Comment: @ElliotDeNolf Yes, your understanding is correct. That 5 minutes is not of any concern. It might change or could be a continuous loop. Not sure yet. I just need to know the highest value of X at any given time, when I execute my AHK script.

Comment: for some reason, the final form of this script didn't work for me. I am getting a blank msgbox at the end.I thought it was because of different interpretation of % at the msgbox but none of the different iterations I tried worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just let the system get the value for you.

```
RunWait,%comspec% /v:on /c "( for /f "tokens=2" `%f in ('findstr /b /r /c:"prog [0-9]+" c:\users\me\test.txt ') do set max=`%f ) & exit /b !max!",,UseErrorLevel
MsgBox %ErrorLevel%
```